# What is the meaning of local[4] in this example

Tags: bash, java, maven

I am looking at this example from the [apache spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) documentation. It seems to pass a variable called local[4] into the --master variable. I have not seen that before. What does it mean? I am using bash on OS X. Is there a "local" array? Is it a maven construct?

```
# Package a jar containing your application
$ mvn package
...
[INFO] Building jar: {..}/{..}/target/simple-project-1.0.jar

# Use spark-submit to run your application
$ YOUR_SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
  --class "SimpleApp" \
  --master local[4] \
  target/simple-project-1.0.jar
...
Lines with a: 46, Lines with b: 23
```

Comment: If that's a command to be run in a shell, then `local[4]` is of no significance to the shell. The application may care about it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Spark question, not a bash or Maven issue. For Spark, the master name can be in the form:

> local[K]: Run Spark locally with K worker threads (which should be set
>   to the number of cores on your machine).

Check out https://github.com/mesos/spark/wiki/Spark-Programming-Guide#master-names for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets <strike>do not have a special meaning in this context</strike> are a [globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) feature ("character range") in this context, so with default configuration (`nullglob` off) it will pass literal string `local4` if there is a file `local4` in the working directory, and `local[4]` otherwise (thanks [@Celada](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183933/what-is-the-meaning-of-local4-in-this-example/183949?noredirect=1#comment306571_183949)).

This is not a variable reference (`${local[4]}` would be an [array index substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)).

Comment: That is only true if there is not a file in the current directory called `local4`!